# How can we add complex preprocessing in AWS Sagemaker inference

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS Sagemaker to deploy my speech models trained outside of Sagemaker. I am able to convert my model into something Sagemaker would understand and have deployed it as an endpoint. Problem is that Sagemaker directly loads the model and calls .predict to get the inference. I am unable to figure out where can I add my preprocessing functions in the deployed model. It is suggested to use AWS Lambda or another server for preprocessing. Is there any way I can incorporate complex preprocessing (cannot be done by simple Scikit, Pandas like framework) in Sagemaker itself?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to adjust the predictor.py file in the container that you are bringing your speech models in. Assuming you are using Bring Your Container to deploy these models on SageMaker you will want to adjust the predictor code to include the preprocessing functionality that you are working with. For any extra dependencies that you are working with make sure to update this in your Dockerfile that you are bringing. Having the preprocessing functionality within the predictor file will make sure your data is transformed, processed as you desire before returning predictions. This will add to the response time however, so if you have heavy preprocessing workloads or ETL that needs to occur you may want to look into a service as AWS Glue (ETL) or Kinesis (real-time data streaming/data transformation). If you choose to use Lambda you want to keep in mind the 15 minute timeout limit.

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own